# Ending ColdFusion user session among all tabs if user logs out from one tab

Tags: javascript, html, session, coldfusion

Suppose I log into an application, and open the same application in another tab. If the user logs out from one tab, the other tab persists to be log in.

I have used this to clear the session:

```
<cfset StructClear(SESSION)>
<cflogout>
```

Can anyone provide a solution to log out from all tabs if user logs out from a single tab.

Comment: "<cfset StructClear(SESSION)>
   <cflogout>"

Comment: For this you have to use cookies or local storage. Session are for the same tab they can't  use the others tab session even though when they are pointing to the same url

Comment: This is a long answer but it's been working for me for years.  If a user signs out of one tab all other open tabs will go back to the sign in page as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21740169/3112803